# how to send a email?

Tags: python, django

help please send e-mail. I made a form. after sending her there is a record in the database and sending emails.

views.py:

```
def feedback(request):  
    '''
    page for output feedback form
    '''
    feedback_form =  FeedbackForm() 

    if request.method == 'POST':    
        feedback_form =  FeedbackForm(request.POST) 

        if feedback_form.is_valid():    
            username = request.POST.get('username', '') 
            subject = request.POST.get('subject', '')   
            email = request.POST.get('email', '')   
            message = request.POST.get('message', '')   

            try:
                Feedback.objects.create(
                    username=username.strip(), 
                    subject=subject.strip(), 
                    email=email.strip(), 
                    message=message.strip(), 
                )

                send_mail(
                    subject,
                    message,
                    email,                          # sender email
                    ['mailsender2015@yandex.ru'],   # my email
                )               
            except:
                print('error in try block')
            else:
                t = loader.get_template('page_feedback_ok.html')
                c = RequestContext(request, {}) 

                return HttpResponse(t.render(c))    

    t = loader.get_template('page_feedback.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {       
        'feedback_form': feedback_form,
    })  

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Entry into the database is running and sending letters is not working

console output:

```
 error in try block
```

Comment: Can you show us the send_mail function's code too and the traceback.

Comment: Also show your Feedback model if possible.

Comment: Do you have EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD configured?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure that problem is that you don't have EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD ... so you don't have permissions to send mail

Comment: Maybe you get more help by the program if you output the exception message instead of an uninformative "error in try block"?

Comment: What if you change else to finally?